# Инициализация деки множеством значений

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пробовал написать свою деку и краем глаза увидел на одном из сайтов инициализацию списка `list <int> this_list = {4, 6, 3, 2};` и захотел сделать подобное со своей двусторонней очередью,но не нашёл информации по этому поводу.Как это сделать на примере моего кода или любого похожего кода?

```
template <class T>
struct Elem_que
{
    T value;
    Elem_que<T>* next;
    Elem_que<T>* pre;
};

template <class T>
class deca
{
private:
    Elem_que<T>* HeadPtr;
    Elem_que<T>* LastPtr;
    int length;
public:
    deca<T>();
    ~deca<T>();
    Elem_que<T>* get_HeadPtr();
    Elem_que<T>* get_LastPtr();
    bool isempty();
    void push_to_head(T a);
    void push_to_last(T a);
    void pop_head();
    void pop_last();
    void clear();

    Elem_que<T>* get_element(Elem_que<T>*, int);
};

template <class T>
deca<T>::deca()
{
    HeadPtr = nullptr;
    LastPtr = nullptr;
    length = 0;
}

template <class T>
deca<T>::~deca()
{
}

template <class T>
Elem_que<T>* deca<T>::get_HeadPtr()
{
    return HeadPtr;
}

template <class T>
Elem_que<T>* deca<T>::get_LastPtr()
{
    return LastPtr;
}

template <class T>
bool deca<T>::isempty()
{
    return !this->length;
}

template <class T>
void deca<T>::push_to_head(T a)
{
    if (this->isempty())
    {
        HeadPtr = new Elem_que<T>;
        LastPtr = HeadPtr;
        HeadPtr->value = a;
        HeadPtr->next = nullptr;
        HeadPtr->pre = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        Elem_que<T>* tmp = new Elem_que<T>;
        HeadPtr->next = tmp;
        tmp->next = nullptr;
        tmp->pre = HeadPtr;
        HeadPtr = tmp;
        HeadPtr->value = a;
    }
    length++;
}

template <class T>
void deca<T>::push_to_last(T a)
{
    if (this->isempty())
    {
        HeadPtr = new Elem_que<T>;
        LastPtr = HeadPtr;
        HeadPtr->value = a;
        HeadPtr->next = nullptr;
        HeadPtr->pre = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        Elem_que<T>* tmp = new Elem_que<T>;
        tmp->next = LastPtr;
        tmp->pre = nullptr;
        LastPtr->pre = tmp;
        LastPtr = tmp;
        LastPtr->value = a;
    }
    length++;
}

template <class T>
void deca<T>::pop_head()
{
    if (!this->isempty())
    {
        if (this->length == 1)
        {
            delete HeadPtr;
            HeadPtr = nullptr;
            LastPtr = HeadPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            Elem_que<T>* tmp = HeadPtr;
            HeadPtr = tmp->pre;
            HeadPtr->next = nullptr;
            delete tmp;
        }
        length--;
    }
}

template <class T>
void deca<T>::pop_last()
{
    if (!this->isempty())
    {
        if (this->length == 1)
        {
            delete LastPtr;
            HeadPtr = nullptr;
            LastPtr = HeadPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            Elem_que<T>* tmp = LastPtr;
            LastPtr = tmp->next;
            LastPtr->pre = nullptr;
            delete tmp;
        }
        length--;
    }
}

template <class T>
void deca<T>::clear()
{
    while (HeadPtr)
    {
        pop_head();
    }
}

template <class T>
Elem_que<T>* deca<T>::get_element(Elem_que<T>* temp, int index_elem)
{
    Elem_que<T>* iter_elem = temp;
    if (index_elem < length)
    {
        if (temp->pre == NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < index_elem; i++)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < index_elem; i++)
            {
                temp = temp->pre;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в класс соответствующий конструктор - что-то вроде

```
template <class T>
deca<T>::deca(initializer_list<T> l)
{
    HeadPtr = nullptr;
    LastPtr = nullptr;
    length = 0;
    for(auto t: l) push_to_last(t);
}
```